# onset of oxidation for cyclic voltammetry

Tags: analytical-chemistry, cyclic-voltammetry

I have plotted a cyclic voltagram for my different polymer blends and I am trying to work out the onset of oxidation. picture below is my graph

[image]

from this website: https://www.ossila.com/pages/cyclic-voltammetry
There is a diagram which shows how the straight line should be placed so that it intersects the horizontal line, and thus the onset of oxidation can be found

[image]

However I am being told to draw my lines like this:

[image]

The procedure I am being told to do, doesnt make sense to me, I dont think the data from that would be useful. I would only get values for the Eonset that are very similar if I were to do it the way I'm being told. From my data, theres a clear difference in oxidation slope, so wouldn't it make sense to plot the diagonal line against that slope, rather than a small section near the beginning? From my 5 cyclic voltagrams, it would make much more sense if I were to do it as the website has told me to. There are more pictures on google which do it that way too

Comment: The answer by Farooq is detailed and clear. But as a further help, as I suppose you are on something practical, I leave a comment. Basically all CVs are typical for a solid film and quite irreversible. I would say that they show the same behaviour. If your aim is to link ox pot to the % shown, that is a hard task bcz the plot does not show one (or a simple one). If they would be my data, the polymer is insensitive to the parameter changed. *Forced* to analyse the data in depth, than you are right, take the steeper slopes. But to which intercept? This is a real experiment, not a book....

Comment: In other words, the first slope can also be the onset of real polymer oxidation and not (just) baseline current. Run also a blank for that purpose...

Comment: Also, don't expect to much change in EC because they are blends! Polymers are molecules, their oxidation potential will be basically unchanged EXCEPT for (in principle) conformational change and or counterions diffusion (the latter affecting the shape rather than onset, see it as a source of overpotential needed and a kinetic brake). In a paper of mine, those data would be treated in a vague way (no effect, as expected, and the like......).

Comment: @Alchimista , thank you for your comments, im an undergrad student and havent been taught much on CV, so my knowledge is more general. I am forced to use cv data as I havent been given anything else (cannot enter labs due to pandemic). Could I comment on the slope changes for the blends? where 20% provides increased charge mobility/ion diffusion and 50% there is sort of a degradation of the mobility?

Comment: well that right the kind of speculation one can do. But which one? I should know all the details and other results....But you got what kind of discussion we are about....

Comment: Im not quite sure what info I can share with you, however I am mixing a polymer with PEO (0%,10%,20%,30%,50%) and its scanned at 50mv/s. Im discussing my results, however I feel like my work is not detailed due to lack of data, so I'm out here just trying to put some words together

Comment: In short,:from those CVs only, you can't say anything except describing in words what it is already in the plots

Answer (score 3):

Please don't apply the reversible CV diagram on something which is clearly a non-classical cyclic voltammogram. When you experimentally don't get the shape as predicted by the theory, it means it that particular theoretical model does not apply in your case.

Look at three different types of voltammograms in this picture. Does your CV look like a reversible one? If not, then you were comparing an apple with an orange.

[image]

There is a very nice article which is relevant to you case:
Practical Aspects of Cyclic Voltammetry: How to Estimate Reduction Potentials When Irreversibility Prevails,  Journal of The Electrochemical Society, 2019,  166(5):H3175-H3187

This figure is relevant:
[image]

Examples of cyclic voltammograms showing chemically reversible and irreversible oxidation with designated potentials: E a = anodic potential, E c = cathodic potential, E (i) = inflection-point potential, E (p/2) = half-peak potential, E (e) = edge potential.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I'm being told that I should treat my graphs as reversibel as oxidation and reduction is observed, even though it doesnt look like the reversible picture youve put.

Comment: Whoever is telling you that must provide the "proof" of reversibility. It does not look reversible at all.